# PHP Fetch all Attributes from xml

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml parsed with simplexml_load_string:

```
<ItemAttributes>
                <Binding>Misc.</Binding>
                <Brand>Gotcha</Brand>
                <Feature>schöne Kontraststickerei</Feature>
                <Feature>langer und taillierter Schnitt</Feature>
                <Feature>kleine Kängurutasche</Feature>
                <Feature>Druckknopfleiste mit großen Metallknöpfen</Feature>
                <Feature>Rückseite figurbetonend gerafft</Feature>
                <ProductGroup>Sports</ProductGroup>
                <ProductTypeName>SPORTING_GOODS</ProductTypeName>
                <Title>Gotcha Damen Strickjacke</Title>
            </ItemAttributes>
```

And want to fetch all "Feature" within on Array key. actually i'm doing like this:

```
$response = array(
            "details" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Feature)
);
```

With that i only fetch the first attribute. The "schöne Kontraststickerei". but i want to have all attributes in the $response['details']. in best case comma separated.

Comment: show how are loading the xml content

Comment: `$response = array();
foreach ($item->children() as $node) {
        $response[] = $node->Feature;
}
print_r($response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast each simple XML object to an array:

```
$response = array(
    "details" => htmlentities((string) implode(",",(array) $item->ItemAttributes->Feature))
);
```

Comment: that's it! Thanks a lot!